# Backtracking worst time complexity of this recursive function

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public static void generateWords(List<List<String>> words) {
    generateWordsHelper("", words);
}

public static void generateWordsHelper(String prefix, List<List<String>> words) {
    if (words.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; words.size() > 0 && j < words.get(i).size(); j++) {
            generateWordsHelper(prefix + words.get(i).get(j), words.subList(i+1, words.size()));
        }
    }
}
```

Hi folks,
What would be the worst time complexity of this function, and how do I compute it. Because it's back-tracking, I feel like it's O(2^n), but I have no way of proving it, or explaining why that's the case.

Comment: What is `n`?  Your `words` is a list of lists, so I don't know whether `n` is the total number of `String`s in the list, or the size of `words` (the number of `List<String>`s).

Comment: @ajb what would be the worst time complexity of the function; clearly I am wrong by thinking in terms of n when I have a list of of list strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to express this in terms of the total number of `String`s in the list, because there are two variables involved: the number of `List<String>` elements of the outer list, and the number of `String` elements in each `List<String>`.

To simplify, suppose we assume that *m* = `words.size()`, and each `List<String>` has *k* elements.  (In real life, all the `List<String>`s won't necessarily have the same size.)  Then the total number of `String`s in the list is *n = mk*.  Let's count the total number of times `generateWordsHelper` is called.  If *m* = 0, we call it once, but the function never calls itself recursively.  If *m* = 1, the function is called once, and then we call it recursively *k* times (because of the `int j` loop), but each time we call it, it will be called on a sublist of size 0.  If *m* = 2, the function is called once, and then the function calls itself recursively *k* times with a sublist of size 1, and *k* times with a sublist of size 0 [but not in that order]; if *m* = 3, it calls itself recursively *k* times with a sublist of size 2, again with a sublist of size 1, again with a sublist of size 0.  So we can see the pattern.  If we denote *f*(*m*) to be the total number of times `generateWordHelper` is called when the initial size is *m*, then

*f*(0) = 1
   *f*(*m*) = 1 + *k* * *f*(*m*-1) + *k* * *f*(*m*-2) + ... + *k* * *f*(0)

which works out to

*f*(0) = 1
   *f*(1) = 1 + *k*
   *f*(2) = 1 + 2*k* + *k*<sup>2</sup>
   *f*(3) = 1 + 3*k* + 3*k*<sup>2</sup> + *k*<sup>3</sup>

or

*f*(*m*) = (*k*+1)<sup>*m*</sup>

So I think that's the formula you're looking for: *O*((*k*+1)<sup>*m*</sup>).  I don't think this can be simply expressed in one variable *n*, where *n* is the total number of strings.  If each `List<String>` contains one element, so that *k* = 1 and *n* = *m*, then the number of recursive calls is indeed *O*(2<sup>*n*</sup>)--or actually, exactly 2<sup>*n*</sup>.  If we say the *average* size of each `List<String>` is *z*, then we'll probably get close by using the formula with *k* = *z* and *m* = *n*/*z*, so that the complexity is *O*((*z*+1)<sup>*n*/*z*</sup>).

Note, though, that I've computed "complexity" only in terms of the number of times the recursive method is called.  This doesn't account for the `String` operation `prefix + words.get(i).get(j)` possibly being proportional to one of the variables.